# If I open a sql server connection in a VBA function do I need to close it at then end of the function, or does it close automatically?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

If I open a sql server connection in a VBA function do I need to close it explicitly, or does it close automatically at the end of the function?

It's an adodb connection to as SQL server db from Access.

Comment: See this link on why you should close the connection: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143895/making-repeated-adodb-queries-from-excel-sql-server

Comment: It depends upon the situation. If you want to persist the recordset, you may or may not want to persist the connection as well. This question is too broad, if you share code and a goal I can try and answer it.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is unmanaged code so you should explicitly close the connection. If you are not going to reopen the connection later and the object is still in scope (can't say without seeing your code), also set the object to `Nothing` to dispose of the object too.

I'll add in .NET languages with managed providers that implement `IDisposable`, one can employ a `using` block so that connections are automatically closed and disposed when they become out of scope, eliminating the need to close and dispose connections.

Comment: VBA is managed code. Setting to `Nothing` is pointless unless you want to dispose of objects early (before the function ends)

Comment: .@ErikA, your comment is valid but by managed, I meant managed .NET. Without any code in the question, I made no assumptions about the connection object scope.

Comment: Well, object scope is highly relevant. VBA does feature terminate handlers, and ADODB connections are generally able to close themselves just fine after the garbage collector kicks in. However, all recordsets based on the connection get a reference to the connection so keep it alive, which may or may not be wanted. A general _always close and set to nothing_ may lead to to trouble, especially when binding recordsets to forms.

Comment: @ErikA, completely agree. I added a note about scope to my answer.